# $3+3$ representation of $SO(4)$

Tags: group-theory, lie-algebra, group-representations

In Zee's Group Theory in a Nutshell book, he says that the antisymmetric tensor $A^{ij}$ furnishes a 6 dimensional representation of $SO(4)$. He further argues that this 6 dimensional representation can be broken up into two 3 dimensional representations by listing the following grouping ($A^{14}$, $A^{24}$, $A^{34}$) and ($A^{12}$, $A^{23}$, $A^{31}$). Why does this make sense? Why do the elements in each group only transform amongst themselves?

Answer (score 4):

1. OP is correct: The Lie algebra isomorphism $$so(4)~\cong~ so(3)_+~\oplus~ so(3)_-\tag{1}$$ uses (anti)self-dual real antisymmetric $4\times 4$ matrices, respectively, cf. e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/85833/11127) Math.SE post.
2. However Ref. 1 is trying to make another point. Instead Ref. 1 is discussing [branching rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_representation) for the subgroup $$H:=SO(3)~\ni R ~\mapsto~ \begin{pmatrix} R & \vec{0}\cr \vec{0}^t & 1 \end{pmatrix}_{4\times 4}~\in ~ G:=SO(4).\tag{2}$$
   In this specific embedding (2) of the subgroup, the
   explicit splitting of the $G$-representation into irreducible $H$-representations
   $${\bf 6}_G\cong {\bf 3}_H\oplus {\bf 3}_H\tag{3}$$
   is as Zee writes:
   $$\begin{align} A^{\prime 4i}~=~&R^i{}_j A^{4j}, \cr
   A^{\prime k\ell} ~=~& R^k{}_iA^{ij} R^{\ell}{}_j, \cr i,j,k,\ell~\in~&\{1,2,3\}.\end{align}\tag{4} $$

References:

1. A. Zee, *Group Theory in a Nutshell for Physicists,* 2016; p. 197.

Comment: I agree. I think the way to fix it is to consider $\frac{A^{ij}+B^{ij}}{2}$ and $\frac{A^{ij}-B^{ij}}{2}$ where $B$ is the dual of $A$.

Comment: $ $ Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

The Lie algebras of SO(4) and SU(2)$\times$SU(2) are isomorphic, so the you can get representations of SO(4) former by taking the tensor product of two representations of SU(2).